Trying to apply real-time data processing to random data with Pyspark, but nothing is being generated
This is just a sample, I want to use a more complex RTDP process once I get the basic code working.
Here's the code I tried:
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.streaming import StreamingContext
import time
import random

# Initialize SparkContext and StreamingContext
sc = SparkContext("local[2]", "RandomDataStream")
ssc = StreamingContext(sc, 1)  # Batch interval of 1 second

def generate_data():
    while True:
        data = random.randint(1, 100)
        print("Generated data:", data)
        yield data
        time.sleep(0.5)  # Wait for half a second

def process_data(data):
    filtered_data = data.filter(lambda x: x % 2 == 0)
    sum_of_data = filtered_data.reduce(lambda x, y: x + y)
    print("Sum of even numbers in this batch:", sum_of_data)
    return sum_of_data

stream = ssc.queueStream([sc.parallelize([])]).map(lambda _: generate_data())
processed_stream = stream.map(process_data)

# Print processed data for debugging
processed_stream.foreachRDD(lambda rdd: rdd.foreach(print))

# Start the streaming context
print("Starting Spark Streaming context...")
ssc.start()

# Wait for the termination of the streaming context
print("Awaiting termination...")
ssc.awaitTermination()

The only output I'm getting is:
Starting Spark Streaming context...
Awaiting termination...
What am I doing wrong?

Try replacing rdd.foreach(print) with print(rdd.collect()) where you are printing the processed data for debugging.

@VikasSharma this is a bit better, now I'm getting empty brackets instead of nothing at all.  Could there also be something wrong with my generate_data() function?
